# Why do not more top-level domains have A or MX records

Tags: dns, web

Some top level domains have their own A records. For example, [ai.](http://ai.) is a legitimate website because .ai (Angulia) top-level domain name has A record (they also have MX record, which allows sending mail to *name@ai.*)

However, most of the domains do not have this record. For example, com does not and thus [com.](http://com.) is not a thing, even though that would make a perfectly reasonable and neat name for domain name registrar (for example).

Moreover, some domains that are tied to organizations could be used as the main page of this organization. For example, Google created .google domain name some time ago and they could use [google.](http://google.) as their main page (in addition to [google.com](http://google.com)). Democratic party might have used [democrat.](http://democrat.) as their main website as could republicans use [republican.](http://republican.)

So, why don't more top-level domains name have A (and other records) and websites attached to them?

Also, why when such records exist the way to get to the website is to add a dot after the domain ([ai.](http://ai.) instead of [.ai](http://.ai))? Adding it before the domain seems more consistent to me.

Comment: Probably because it would be incredibly confusing, and prone to mishandling (e.g. by users who are clueless about how the system works, and expect an Internet address to have "www." and ".com") and technical problems (e.g. due to validation scripts that don't cater for this situation)? Either way, not a good fit for Stack Overflow I'm afraid

Comment: There are plenty of resources and background articles on DNS and it's history.  Google is your friend.  First and foremost, DNS predates the web by a decade.  But the reason things are the way they are have to do with how DNS is governed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For older TLDs, because it's confusing and a whole lot of software cannot handle it correctly. Some, like `.ai` do anyway, as you have spotted.

For the newer gTLDs, like `.google`, ICANN's application rules specify that they must not have A or MX records (apart from temporarily the special "if you used this name internally you're about to have a problem" records before the gTLD went live).

Comment: Links for people who want to learn more: [ICANN's announcement](https://www.icann.org/en/announcements/details/new-gtld-dotless-domain-names-prohibited-30-8-2013-en) and [RFC 7085](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7085), which includes a list of dotless domains and a Bash script to determine them.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your final question: all domain names, when fully qualified (which means all the parent domains are expressed, all the way to the DNS root), end with a period. This period represents the DNS root itself. E.g. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). is a FQDN (fully qualified domain name). Now of course, nowadays we usually drop the final period, because the context is usually enough to understand what we mean with no ambiguity.

But that ceases to be the case when the domain is a top level domain, because in that case it is just a single word. Single words are often used in local networks, to describe a specific host. Besides, typing a single word (or anything that does not resemble what John Doe would call a "domain name", e.g. a few words separated by spaces) in most browser URL bars nowadays will lead to the default search engine (usually Google) searching this string, instead of trying to resolve it using DNS. Adding the period removes the ambiguity: it can no longer be a local hostname, or a search engine query.

Funny and related: I remember using a tool to perform DNS requests, and I would ask it to resolve "fr" (the French TLD). It worked, because it recognized it as a domain. But when I tried with "ch", I got an error. For Switzerland, the final dot was needed (in other words, the FQDN was needed). Why? Because the tool thought I was referencing the CH (chaos) DNS class! You know, the alternative to IN (internet) that was initially a set of protocol besides TCP/IP that never really caught up and is nowadays "abused" by bind to display version and author information.